# Intercept setObject functions on class properties in Swift

Tags: swift, properties

I have the line `var user = BRUser()` at the top of my Swift file *class* `BRProfileTableViewCell`.
`BRUser` is a *struct* with details such as `fullName`, etc. I set the `user` value in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in my table view controller.

How could I intercept the `setUser` function to set the label text of the table view cell to the `fullName` of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't need to **intercept** anything, but rather you need to **observe** changes in the property, and for that, you want Swift's property observers:

```
var user: BRUser = BRUser() {
    willSet {
        // do something just before user is set
    }
    didSet {
        // do something just after user is set
    }
}
```